React compenent data do not update as expected on rerendering
I have a component which receives a prop that is my API requested data:
<Table apidata={apiData} filters={filters}/>

const  Table = ({apiData, ...props}) => {
const [webtax, setWebtax] = useState(false)

const tableData = apiData.map(item=> {

 item.cost = webtax ? item.cost + 100 : item.cost
 //....

return item
})

//..more code...

return (
<>
.......
</>
)
}

Inside Table component I need to manipulate some values when "webtax" prop change status.
For some reason I can't figure out why "item.cost" just increases anytime the status switches from FALSE to TRUE. For example, updating 3 time webtax status (from checkbox event) "item.cost" value becomes +300.
I expect "item.cost" result equal to its value + 100 or its original value (-100).
I tried also to use useMemo() or useEffect() and use webtax as prop outside component but nothing changed.
apiData is loaded once form API before rendering and do not update until new form submit event.
Thanks
